# Mongodb set a maximum value for a field?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Quick question, is there a way for a field to have a maximum value in mongodb? For example the field “cards” can only have a maximum value of 100. So if you would increment above it it would return to its maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

In mongoose:

```
const testSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  value: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 100, default: 0 }
});
```

If value 100 and you want to increment this it return error

Comment: Alright, and is there also a way to not have it have an error but to make it go to it maximums value, instead of going over it?

Comment: Hmm i tested it but it seems that i can still go above100 for some reason.

Comment: @SpringerJerry not it's not possible, because mongoose provides validation for the schema in this case. It's not a hard limit for the Mongo itself. 
Also, if Sergey provided a useful answer for your question, would you be kind and accept it as an answer or upvote it at least?